# Process terminates while wait() is isssued

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, wait

What happens when a process terminates and a wait() is issued for it? What happens when a child terminates but no one does a wait() for it?  hat happens if you do a wait() for a process that has not terminated yet?

Comment: I found out what happens when a child terminates and parent doesn't wait, the child process becomes a zombie.

Answer (score 4):

Let me know if I missunderstood the questions:

- > what happens when a process terminates and a wait() is isssued for it?

  The terminated process returns its exit status to its parent, who
  used `wait`.
- > What happens when a child terminates but no one does a wait() for it?

  As you said in your comment, the terminated child becomes a zombie
  process, until its parent gets its exit status, using `wait`.
- > What happens if you do a wait() for a process that has not terminated
  >   yet?

  Usually, the process that did  the `wait` will block until it gets its child's    exit status (Although it can be told not to block, using `waitpid(2)`, another system call in the "`wait` group of system calls", which gives more options). By block, we mean it will suspend its execution while the child process executes. When the child process terminates, it returns to OS an exit status. That exit status is then returned to its parent process who used `wait`, which resumes its execution after getting it.

---

As far as zombie processes are concerned :

When a process dies, its children processes automatically become children of `init`, which is a process only used to do `wait`. So, if a zombie process's parent dies without `wait` to get its zombie child's exit status, then `init` will do it, as it will become zombie process's new parent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. In the third answer what does block mean ?can you please elaborate? also am I correct in saying that all zombie process will be terminated by the init process ?

Comment: @Duck +1. I should have mentioned `waitpid` at that point. I'll edit now.

Comment: @user3304140 a process remains in zombie state until it's parent does a wait for it and reads the exit status of the child. If the parent has also terminated without reading the exit status then init process does this task.If the parents does not want to wait for the child to finish then "WNOHANG" can be used.